# PHP compare time from SQL database with current time

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I would like to check if a time in an SQL database is more than a day old.
I am able to read the datetime off the SQL row and get the current time. What I am unable to do, however, is add 1 day/24 hours to the time pulled from the row, and comparing the 2.

```
$currenttime = date("Y-m-d h:m:s");
$tmstp = $row['datetime'];
$newtime = date("Y-m-d h:m:s", $tmstp);
echo $tmstp."<br>".$currenttime."<br>".$newtime;
```

returns the following:

```
Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 12
0000-00-00 00:00:00
2016-03-12 09:03:39
1970-01-01 01:01:00
```

the null time is to be expected, I initialized the row but didn't pass a value to it. Setting it to anything other than null(including setting it to an arbitrary date more than 24 hours ago but after 1970-1-1 OR adding one hour to it:

```
$currenttime = date("Y-m-d h:m:s");
$tmstp = $row['datetime'] + strtotime('+ 24 hours');
$newtime = date("Y-m-d h:m:s", $tmstp);
echo $tmstp."<br>".$currenttime."<br>".$newtime;
```

sets it to tomorrow at this time:

```
1457903185
2016-03-12 10:03:25
2016-03-13 10:03:25
```

Once I can get the expected values, how would I effectively compare the 2 values? 
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

For compare times you can use the `strtotime` like this:

```
$tomorrow = strtotime('+ 24 hours');
$timestamp = strtotime($row['datetime']);

if ($timestamp > $tomorrow) {
    // The date in database is greater than tomorrow
}
```